# My hair particles is missing when i export my model (or when apply my modifiers)

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, particles, hair

Well, I created an arena for my game and added some grass using just the hair particles. Apparently everything is fine, but when I export my model or apply the modifiers the hair particle just disappear.

This is my model.

[image]

And this is my model after export
[image]

I don't know what's wrong.
PS: I tried to create a vertex group, but nothing changed. And I tried to convert the particles to mesh (I tried curve too), but the shape of the grass changes to a "stick" and when I try to give some volume to my grass, it turns into some kind of round straw.

My real question is "How to export both the grass and the model together."

Comment: Hi! I presume your using the hair option in eeve as the grass strands.
I would suggest you to create a object similar to the grass strand and Instance it.

Comment: @Nand27 I had already tried, but that gave me another problem. When I do this, the shader just bugs. I mean, the shader stays on the object and doesn't form a color pattern like in the pics above. It's like my color ramp doesn't exist.

Comment: I should clear up some things here...
In order to have a particle system with a object as Instance and also have a texture on it then you have to use the cycles engine.

Comment: if your using the cycles engine then make sure to enable the "from instancer" in the texture coordinate input or else it wouldn't work.